# Unable to delete data from firebase using the web GUI

Tags: firebase

I am trying to delete data from firebase simply using the web GUI at "https://my-app-name.firebaseio.com" When I hold shift and press the red x for delete the selected data is deleted, and then an exact copy of the same data is created at the same time. I can see this quite clearly because of the red for delete, green for new data color scheme that firebase has. I have no idea why this is happening. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I just deleted a node from my Firebase dashboard by holding down shift and clicking on the red X. It disappeared and did not reappear. Given the sequence you see, it sounds as if some code is adding the item back immediately after it's deleted.

Comment: @Josh did you ever sort this?

Comment: The solution for me was to just reboot my computer entirely.